# Input Text format, Jquery, Javascript or Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation, user-input

While Typing in a input First letter should change to Capital, But rest letters should be in lowercase, Even user Input capital letters it should changed it lowercase.

Example input word: mOuSe , ComPuTER

**Important Point:** **While Typing it should change to:**  Mouse, Computer

I have tried many Stackflow soloution, But for above logic i found none.

**Using Css:**  [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbxVx/33/)

**Using Javacript:**  [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbxVx/5/)  (This one worked but for last letter it doesnt works)

Any solution is accepted using Jquery, Javascript or Css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert('ready');

  $('input').on('keypress', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.val();

        val = val.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        $this.val(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your JS fiddle (the last one) worked for me? What is the issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `input` event instead of the `keypress` event.

```
 $('input').on('input', function(event) {
```

Comment: I think that `keyup` event is better

Comment: `keyup` won't fire if the user pastes into the field

Comment: No you re wrong keyup is better and yes it will fire on paste

Comment: Keyup will not fire if you paste using the mouse. It may if you paste using a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

```
function initCap(t){    
t.value=t.value.toLowerCase();  
t.style='text-transform:capitalize;'
}
```

call the method onkeypress and onblur

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(event) {
    var firstchar = $(this).val().substring(0,1);
    var remainchar = $(this).val().substring(1,$(this).val().length).toLowerCase();
    $(this).val(firstchar + remainchar);
});
$('input').on('keydown', function(event) {
    var firstchar = $(this).val().substring(0,1);
    var remainchar = $(this).val().substring(1,$(this).val().length).toLowerCase();
    $(this).val(firstchar + remainchar);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbxVx/37/)

Comment: It works, but there is a bug in chrome browser version 34, You cant move left arrow arrow key to backwards. Any way this solution was also helpfull Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be interesting to point out that CSS `text-transform: capitalize;` only alters the **display** of the input, while Javascript modifies the actual **HTML value**. This matters if the input is, for example, a CAPTCHA response or form input field that needs to be validated.

With pure Javascript, you could split the input into separate words & transform each one of them, like so:

HTML

```
<div id="transform">mOuSE, cOmPUTEr</div>
<button type="button">Capitalize</button>
```

JS

```
var rgx = /,/; /* word splitter, can be anything */
var target = document.getElementById('transform');
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {
  var strArr = target.innerHTML.split(rgx); /* split the input */
  for (var word = 0; word < strArr.length; word++) { /* iterate over each word */
     strArr[word] = strArr[word].toLowerCase().trim(); 
     var firstLetter = strArr[word].substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
     var otherLetters = strArr[word].substr(1, strArr[word].length)
     strArr[word] = firstLetter+otherLetters;
  }
  target.innerHTML = strArr.join();
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/farib/2/edit

NB: If your input is in a `<textarea>` or `<input>`, replace `.innerHTML` with `.value`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this css solution.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbxVx/36/)

```
input {
    text-transform:capitalize;
    color: blue;
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").on("keypress",function(){

        $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase());

    });

})
```

Comment: **But rest letters should be in lowercase** while typing even user input capital letter in mid of input value.

Comment: Yes.. did you check the demo?? The result come like this **"Bbbbbbb"**

Comment: Only if you type `bbbbbbb`, if you type `bbbBBB` it comes out as `BbbBBB`